# Updating mongoose schema fields concurrently

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm trying to update a mongoose schema. Basically I have two api's '/follow/:user_id' and '/unfollow/:user_id'. What I'm trying to achieve is whenever user A follows user B , user B followers field in mongoose will increment as one.

As for now I managed to get only following fields increment by one but not the followers fields.

schema.js

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    username: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }},
    password: { type: String, required: true, select: false },
    followers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
    following: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}],
    followersCount: Number,
    followingCount: Number

});
```

**Updated version**: I tried my solution, but whenever I post it, it just fetching the data ( I tried the api's on POSTMAN chrome app ).

api.js

```
    // follow a user



 apiRouter.post('/follow/:user_id', function(req, res) {

        // find a current user that has logged in
            User.update(
                {   
                    _id: req.decoded.id, 
                    following: { $ne: req.params.user_id } 
                }, 

                { 
                    $push: { following: req.params.user_id},
                    $inc: { followingCount: 1}

                },
                function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        res.send(err);
                        return;
                    }

                    User.update(
                        {
                            _id: req.params.user_id,
                            followers: { $ne: req.decoded.id }
                        },

                        {   
                            $push: { followers: req.decoded.id },
                            $inc: { followersCount: 1}

                        }

                    ), function(err) {
                        if(err) return res.send(err);

                        res.json({ message: "Successfully Followed!" });
                    }

            });
    });
```

These codes only manage to increment the user's following fields, and without duplication. How do I update logged in user's **following** fields and as well as other user's followers fields at the same time?

**Updated version**: it keeps fetching the data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be this is how you want to. Instead of using `update`, you can also use `findOneAndUpdate` from Mongoose queries.

```
apiRouter.post('/follow/:user_id', function(req, res) {
    User.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        _id: req.decoded.id
    },
    {
        $push: {following: req.params.user_id},
        $inc: {followingCount: 1}
    },
    function (err, user) {

        if (err) 
            res.send(err);

        User.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            _id: req.params.user_id
        },

        {   
            $push: {followers: req.decoded.id},
            $inc: {followersCount: 1}
        },
        function (err, anotherUser) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({message: "Successfully Followed!"})
        });

    });
}
```

If you are not sure about it is updated or not, you can just use `console.log()` for both `user` and `anotherUser` variables to see changes.

Comment: Thank you for helping, It doesnt work. Its only updating the following and followingCount fields and but not followers and followersCount.

Comment: What did you get when you try `console.log(user)` ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, value for user is shown, but value for anotherUser is null. Looks like asynchronous problem .

Comment: It means the update is not successful probably because user doesn't find. Please check user with `req.params.user_id` is existed in your database. And also I updated the query in answer.

Comment: if I dont put **following: { $ne: req.params.user_id }**, It will duplicate